# How do I create a vertical dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, navigationbar

What I am trying to accomplish here is a vertical drop down menu on the element, (ul) "fav blogs". I trying to adjust the css so it only vertically drops down the sub menus, "rawrmerawr" and "realfriennds" directly under the "fav blogs" element.

No matter what CSS that I am using I cannot figure out what the correct code is that I use. When I hover over the "There's shit here" element it correctly drops down the other (ul - unordered list) but when i am hovering over the "fav blogs" it does not do so.

You can view the nav bar live [here](http://lowheartrate.tumblr.com)

**A look at the html code:**

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">There's some shit here </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">fav blogs </a></li>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="http://rawrmerawr.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">sun&stars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">realfriennds</a></li>

                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">musicc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">only me!!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**A look at the css code:**

```
nav {
position: fixed;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

nav ul ul, ul ul ul li {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

nav ul ul ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure is incorrect. The `<ul>` for the sub-menu should be nested inside the `<li>` for `fav blogs` like this:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">There's some shit here </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">fav blogs </a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://rawrmerawr.tumblr.com/" target="_blank">sun&stars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">realfriennds</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">musicc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">only me!!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this CSS:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li:hover>ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-top: -12px;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
        display: none;
}

nav>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
        display: none;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>ul {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Using the code you provided there still is no dropdown animation on the the element, "fav blogs". Maybe there may be something wrong with the css as well!? If you could take a look that would be fantastic.

Comment: @CodiBezouka-Smith Please check my updated answer above, you will need to use that CSS.